# C++: Array, initializer fails to determine size of

Tags: c++, arrays

I attampted to write a Message Map following a sample in a book.

Here is my code:

```
typedef struct MsgMapEntry_t {  
    UINT nMessage;  
    LONG (*pFunc)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);  
} MsgMapEntry_t;  

// Skip Lines  

LRESULT CALLBACK CyauShellWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)  
{
    static MsgMapEntry_t OnMsgMap[]=  
    (  
        // TODO Register MsgFunc here  
        WM_DESTROY, ExitApplication  
    );
```

Compile it, and the compiler gives out an error:

> D:\Projects\cyau\cyau_pre3_20120225\cyau_main.cpp:116:15: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
>   D:\Projects\cyau\cyau_pre3_20120225\cyau_main.cpp:117:2: error: initializer fails to determine size of 'OnMsgMap'

So, How to correct it, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two pairs of curly braces (one for the array, one for the struct), instead of a single pair of parentheses.

```
static MsgMapEntry_t OnMsgMap[]= { // start the array
    // TODO Register MsgFunc here  
    { // start the struct
    WM_DESTROY, ExitApplication
    } // end the struct; more data can go here after ','
}; // end the array
```

Comment: Technically, you don't *need* two pairs, because nested aggregate initializers are allowed to be "flattened".

Comment: @FredOverflow You are right, but it is probably better to tell about the second pair right away, to avoid a follow up question of "why adding a second element to my array results in compile errors" :)

Comment: @FredOverflow The compiler throw an warning: D:\Projects\cyau\cyau_pre3_20120225\cyau_main.cpp:117:2: warning: missing braces around initializer for 'MsgMapEntry_t {aka MsgMapEntry_t}' [-Wmissing-braces]
>_-, but thank you anyway.

Comment: @cuter44 Did you copy both pairs of curly braces from the answer? The warning is about the inner pair ("start the struct" / "end the struct") missing.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes I know, I just wanna test what FredOverFlow says.

Answer (score 1):

Array initializers use curly braces `{ ... }` instead of parenthesis `( ... )`.

Comment: @cuter44 I think I'm missing some context, what are you talking about?

Comment: "use curly braces { ... } instead of parenthesis ( ... )" <-I just means that, I'm a beginner and need more guildence. >,0